# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: block1_conv1_2/kernel

Tags: javascript, python, keras, tensorflowjs-converter

I am new to machine learning and I was following this [blog](https://github.com/vbookshelf/Skin-Lesion-Analyzer/blob/master/skin-lesion-analyzer-jupyter-notebook%20version%202.ipynb) on how to write a model with mobilenet.

I managed to convert the .h5 file model and tried to implement it 
on my web app.

Unfortunately, when I try to load the JSON model I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target
>   variable: block1_conv1_2/kernel.

[Screenshot of the error on a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJrnC.png)

I converted the .h5 model in the command line like so:

> tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras model.h5 ConvertedModel/

The code to load the model in the browser, I followed this [blog](https://github.com/aryanmisra/Skin-Lesion-Classifier/blob/master/predict.js)

```js
let model;
async function loadModel(name) {
  $(".progress-bar").show(); 
  model = undefined;
  model = await tf.loadModel(`ConvertedModel/model.json`);
    $(".progress-bar").hide();
}
```

To see the code of the model please refer to the [blog link](https://github.com/vbookshelf/Skin-Lesion-Analyzer/blob/master/skin-lesion-analyzer-jupyter-notebook%20version%202.ipynb).
But below is a screenshot of how the model is compiled.
[Model compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2stQ9.png)

Dependencies:

- Tensorflow 1.13.1
- Python 3.6.0
- tensorflowjs 1.0.1

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: I had similar issues, which were resolved by upgrading from 
tfjs `1.2.11` to `1.3.2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you've encountered [this error](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/755) where an extra suffix has been added to some of your weights.

You can work around this issue by manually removing these extra suffixes from your model.json:

```
block1_conv1_2/kernel
```

should instead be:

```
block1_conv1/kernel
```

---

The 'Error in clip' bug has now been [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/908) so I'm not too sure why you've received this one, but once again you can work around this by manually editing the model.json, and changing every instance of:

```
{"type":"ndarray", "value":6}
```

to

```
6
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion took out the error message I had but returned this now 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error in clip: min (0) must be less than or equal to max ([object Object]).
    at assert (util.ts:81)
    at clipByValue_ (unary_ops.ts:335)
    at clipByValue (operation.ts:46)
    at t.call (advanced_activations.ts:59)
    at topology.ts:998
    at nameScope (common.ts:52)
    at t.apply (topology.ts:957)
    at executeInternal (executor.ts:199)
    at executeInternal (executor.ts:194)
    at executeInternal (executor.ts:194)

Comment: @Rstynbl I've updated my answer with the fix for this one too. Hope it helps!

Comment: I belive it should simply be: > "max_value": 6.0, <

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works now! sorry for the last query, silly mistake! thanks for all your help!

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: I have a similar issue: errors.ts:48 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: bidirectional/forward_lstm/lstm_cell_1/kernel , but editing the model.json to remove the extra suffixes does not solve the problem