# Tensorflow JS tfjs | Unable to load model using tf.loadLayersModel

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

While executing the following code embedded in html using WAMP stack

`const model = tf.loadLayersModel('js/model.json');`

I encounter the following errors in chrome

```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

> platform_browser.ts:28 GET http://localhost/poemgenerator/js/group1-shard3of22.bin net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I have all the group1-shard__of22.bin present at the mentioned location

During every run of the code, the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE  is shown on different files.

The tfjs loaded using

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.7.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>`

---

**PS:**

While executing the code IDM starts downloading all the group1-shard__of22.bin files

I The model being loaded was created in python and is a tf.keras model. which has been converted using tfjs converter

---

**Update :**

I used the replaced the above code with

```
async function predict(){
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('js/model.json');
  model.summary()
}
```

And also removed IDM but it showed another errors :

```
> errors.ts:48 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/kernel

> (index):68 Uncaught TypeError: model.summary is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Tensorflow works best in an asynchronous way, you should use an async function with await when loading the model:

```
async function predict(){
  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('js/model.json');
  // do prediction
}
```

Comment: I encountered the following error while  using the above code :                                     `errors.ts:48 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided weight data has no target variable: lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/kernel`

Comment: Please, your first question was ok, but keep your post to one question. And do some research before you ask, I found the solution by just googling your error. Here you can find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295671/uncaught-in-promise-error-provided-weight-data-has-no-target-variable-block1

Comment: I had already googled it, and found this one too, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have the following error: ```Error: Cannot proceed with model loading because the IOHandler provided does not have the `load` method implemented.```

Comment: I think this has to do with something else. Please ask it in a new question with the provided code.